# Excel - AverageIf showing only Filtered Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula (Times superior to 10sec) which is working:
`=AVERAGEIF(A20:A5557;">=10")`

However I want to get this on filtered data. Was playing around with this: `=AVERAGE(IF(SUBTOTAL(2;OFFSET(A20;ROW(A20:A5557)-ROW(A20);0));IF(A20:A5557;">=10";A20:A5557)))`, but without success. How can I use an AverageIf showing only the filtered data?

**Edit**

Got it working with `=AVERAGE(IF(SUBTOTAL(9;OFFSET(A20;ROW(A20:A5557)-ROW(A20);0;1))>10;A20:A5557))`. Now I also wanted to add multiple conditions (Ex: >=5 and <10). Not sure how to add multiple conditions to the previous formula.

Comment: Search for `SUBTOTAL`

Comment: What about using `AVERAGEIFS`?

Comment: @DavidLeal To the best of my knowledge (I'm still new to Excel) the **AVERAGEIFS** doesn't contemplate data being filtered. If I filter half the data out, the AVERAGEIFS will still be the average of the whole data

Comment: @HenriquePombo yes it has to be a range, but you can filter the data with the additional conditions. It is difficult to provide a solution/suggestion without a sample data in your question.